# Nvidia Jetson Nanon GPIO c++ direct memory interfacing

Tags: c++

Is there's any library to interface the Jetson Nano GPIO?
There's the [official Python](https://github.com/NVIDIA/jetson-gpio) interface, and there is an [unofficial c++ interface](https://github.com/pjueon/JetsonGPIO) which is working through the filesystem, and I'm interested in the direct register access.
There is a post [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/what-pins-can-be-used-for-pwm-control-except-33-in-samples/78076/22?page=2) by [someone](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/u/ashtuchkin) who claims he has achived it, but before I re-imlement the [reference manual](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/downloads#?search=Tegra%20X1), It would be great if someone already did it.

Comment: what is preventing you from running tests? ... it is expected that you do research and attempt a solution before you post here

Comment: I don't understand the question, I'm not running any test, I'm searching for a c++ library that access gpio through direct register memory

Comment: you said `There is a post here by someone who claims he has achived it` ..... you could verify the claim

Comment: No link, just claim...

Answer (score 4):

I created a library that does just that, mapping the tegra CPU registers in user space. My lib is here: https://github.com/Rubberazer/JETGPIO it can be called from C or C++